# Magento 2: Upgrade magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.3-p1 issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, upgrade, patches, magento2.4.2-p1

I have tried to upgrade Magento CE from 2.4.3 to 2.4.3-p1 using the following commands:

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 --no-update
composer update

but I am getting this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1, found magento/product-community-edition[0.42.0-beta7, 2.0.0, ..., 2.4.3] but it does not match the constraint.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try this command with "composer update" with iniatl composer.json and lock file than use the require command . I faced similar issue this will update alll the modules for 2.4.3

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: I tried that but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed. The authentication keys were not correct.